# QGIS: Processing tools adding a false edge to vector layer with extreme values

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, qgis-processing

I am working in QGIS 3.34.2 and several processing tools I've used so far have added a thin outline (1 cell wide?) to the edge of my area of interest (see output of aspect tool below).

[image: tools produce false edge with extreme values]

The vector layer I've been using to clip all others (both vector and raster) aligns well with the tool output inside the false outline (see below).  Can anyone tell me if this outline is affecting my project in a material way, and if the answer is a "likely, yes", how can I avoid this from happening?

[image]

Comment: That's because vector layer "cuts" the raster values prior to processing to the vector boundaries.. And processing tools/procedures doesn't have the required data outside of vector. A workaround: add a buffer to vector, process your raster with this buffer added and crop resulting raster with original vector. Or process the whole raster and then cut off the area of interest with vector.